# Integrating TeamViewer SDK: NoClassDefFoundError with NotificationCompat

Tags: android, teamviewer

The question mostly for TeamViewer support, thanks.

I got the error during finishing long free TVSession. If I close connection, it wants to notify me about sponsored things (I suppose) and crashes with

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder
```

Background is important! I integrated your SDK in very old project for old embedded device. It is not gradle, is not using appcompat libraries and has plain old android structure. Actually, android OS 4.3, project SDK API 21, but upper limit is hard:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>
```

So please can you fix it? Or how to prevent using unexistent class? Without importing appcompat libs, please.

Note, establish and keep session successfully, all fine. If I close session in few seconds, all fine.

Logs:

```
2017/02/06 03:41:51.119 I/SessionIncomingRemoteSupport handle session teardown
2017/02/06 03:41:51.119 I/SessionIncomingRemoteSupport Session will be terminated by: partner
2017/02/06 03:41:51.119 I/SessionIncomingRemoteSupport trySessionTeardown: teardown
2017/02/06 03:41:51.120 I/RSModule module stopped: Clipboard
2017/02/06 03:41:51.126 I/SessionIncomingRemoteSupport handle session end
2017/02/06 03:41:51.126 I/SessionIncomingRemoteSupport destroying SessionIncomingRemoteSupport
2017/02/06 03:41:51.126 I/TeamViewer CarrierContainer.SendCarrierSwitch: state=2, carrier=1
2017/02/06 03:41:51.126 I/TeamViewer UdpCarrierDeactivationState::DiscloseStateToCarrier: empty send buffer is not flushed
2017/02/06 03:41:51.127 I/TeamViewer Activating Router carrier
2017/02/06 03:41:51.127 I/RSModuleManager destroy
2017/02/06 03:41:51.128 I/ScreenSharingSDKSession Stopping session
2017/02/06 03:41:51.130 W/TeamViewer UdpConnection[20]: UDP statistics: nb=33
2017/02/06 03:41:51.130 I/SessionIncomingRemoteSupport SessionIncomingRemoteSupport destroyed
2017/02/06 03:41:51.130 I/SessionManager !end session!
2017/02/06 03:41:51.131 I/SessionManager set session is running: false
2017/02/06 03:41:51.134 W/TVWidget widget already removed
2017/02/06 03:41:51.135 I/SessionController close
2017/02/06 03:41:51.135 I/SessionController Release partial wakelock
2017/02/06 03:41:51.136 W/PseudoSocketAdapter read: Socket already closed.
2017/02/06 03:41:51.137 I/BCommandHandler listener thread stopped
2017/02/06 03:41:51.137 W/SessionIncomingRemoteSupport Session already destroyed!
2017/02/06 03:41:51.199 I/TeamViewer TeamViewer is going offline!
2017/02/06 03:41:51.200 I/TeamViewer RemoteSessionManager::ClearAllRemoteSessions(): RemoteSession Count: 2
2017/02/06 03:41:51.211 W/InterProcessGUIConnector Received SessionCommand (SessionCommand ptr=0x62a02db8 rct=12 ct=ConnectionInfo) without registered callback.
2017/02/06 03:41:51.217 I/TeamViewer ConnectionGuard: no restrictions
2017/02/06 03:41:51.218 I/TeamViewer CGatewaySession[18]::EndSession(): Session to 742326611 ended. Estimated capacity=0kBit/s, Latency=3ms
2017/02/06 03:41:51.218 I/TeamViewer CSendCommandToMaster::SendBCommandToMaster: CC=3 CT=37
2017/02/06 03:41:51.294 I/TeamViewer RemoteSessionManager::ClearAllRemoteSessions(): Waited 94ms
2017/02/06 03:41:51.295 I/KeepAlive Offline
2017/02/06 03:41:51.296 I/TeamViewer Account::UpdateState: KA = 0, active = 1
2017/02/06 03:41:51.296 I/TeamViewer Account::SetLoginState: new state: 0
2017/02/06 03:41:51.382 I/TeamViewer TVRouterClock Schedule next request in 0 seconds
2017/02/06 03:41:51.383 W/TeamViewer KeepAliveSessionOutgoing::ConnectEndedHandler(): KeepAliveConnection with server50704.teamviewer.com ended
2017/02/06 03:48:53.041 I/FileManager check storage
2017/02/06 03:48:53.043 I/FileManager copyFilesToExternalStorage: copy TVLog.html
```

Comment: hi please help me to integrate TeamViewer SDK for android. i have created the session successfully but not getting connected. your help will be highly appreciable. thanks

Comment: Please tell me how u integrated... am not able to find it

Answer (score 0):

You can sumbit a ticket for the TeamViewer Support here: https://www.teamviewer.com/ticket/

Comment: unfortunately, they appeal to min SDK=14